# how to make google `repo forall` return false if any command fails in one project?

Tags: shell, version-control, repo

I'm using Google `repo forall -c "<my command>"` in my script to batch execute the command towards all my repo projects, I want to get notified if any of the command fails, what is the best approach for this use case?

I know there is an option `-e` or `--abort-on-errors` however it exits immediately without processing the rest of the projects if a command fails

[edit] trying out the return code:

```
$  repo forall -c 'bash -c "false"'
$  echo $?
$  1
```

Comment: Exit status of `repo forall` seems to be what you want. I get **2**  with `echo $?` when at least one command failed with `repo forall`.

Comment: how did you test this? I updated my post, even all sub commands fail it's return code is still `1`

Comment: I'm using `ls` (on a file I know is there or not) which return 2 when "No such file or directory" so `repo forall` forward command return code.

Answer (score 0):

following @Hugo y's comment I was able to confirm that `repo forall` return code can indicate if any of the command towards each project has any failure:

```
$  repo forall -c 'exit "$(( ( RANDOM%10>5)))"'
[Exit: 1] 
$  repo forall -c 'exit 0'
[Exit: 0] 
$  repo forall -c 'exit 1'
[Exit: 1]
```